# What web development frameworks questions should I include in my thesis?

Tags: web-development, frameworks, web-framework

I'm busy working for my thesis about Web Development Frameworks. I want to write about frameworks that have been used in the past and frameworks that have a good chance of lasting in the future, such as JQuery and PrimeFaces for example. I also want to do a survey and I am looking for good questions to ask on this survey.

My questions is what web developers themselves are most interested in answering and what you think would be good questions in this survey to ask? For example, I was thinking about giving a list of current technologies and giving the possibility to give a score from 1 tot 10 to indicate which they prefer the most.

Comment: Unless you are studying usage trends or developer experience specifically, "which one do you like best" is not probative. Perhaps if you could give us a more concrete idea of what you hope to discern, we could offer specific advice.

Comment: Don't exactly know what you want, but you could start your search here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks This page contains a long list of web app frameworks. If that's what you are looking for. You could find out the popularity in those by doing some research per framework.

Comment: I am currently doing an internship for my thesis at a company. However, the boss likes to work with older technology while the employees have wishes to work with newer things, such as Javaserver Faces combined with PrimeFaces.I want to use my thesis to describe current technologies and compare them with the ones the company uses, and thus showing possible points of improvement. I want to use a survey in a positive way to encourage the use of the newest technologies, and I want to ask good questions so that the local employees can say their opinion in a subtle way through the use of that survey

Comment: I've never heard of PrimeFaces, so I googled it. The term "PrimeFaces" has just over 100k google matches. Which is to say it's barely a blip on the radar. The name of the cute little PHP framework I'm using, Yii, has over 4 million. The term "Zend Framework" has 6 million. Just to put PrimeFaces in perspective for you.

Answer (score 3):

What about commit activity (e.g. on github) or some other measure of participation to show the framework hasn't gone stale. You could also look at surrounding infrastructure (plugins, libraries, etc) to see if people are working on the side rather than the core framework.

Comment: That are indeed some good points to do research on in my thesis itself, and those tips are offcourse also always good to know. But are there any more specific questions you would like to get on a survey or that you think might make an interesting survey in my case?

Comment: +1 - this is a useful metric when my team is deciding on which frameworks appear to have an active community working on them.